# Windows (or online) Web Workflow For A Newbie? (rubygems are confusing)

Tags: windows, rubygems, github, sass, cloud9-ide

i'm a web designer (front-end developer) who would like to use sass+compass and slim-lang (similar to haml, but more lightweight). if you're unfamiliar, these are all rubygems, which parse code and compile to html and css. That's where my understanding ends.

i've been through a few ruby tutorials, but they're ALL geared towards mac users. sadly, i'm a windows user, and i get but a confusing footnote. i tried installing ruby, but none of the commands would work, so i started looking at other solutions (due to windows' sickening lack of a useful command line).

currently i'm looking into using cloud9 for editing and github for compiling (is that even possible?)... but i don't understand git at all. is this overkill? is there an easy way to do this, or at least some concise explanation of all this? i know i'm not stupid; i just feel like there's some key thing i'm missing here.

(note to self: buy a mac)

**tl;dr:**

Things I have:

- windows

Things I need:

- a simple ide to edit code / manage projects
- a simple way to compile slim,compass,sass without a headache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to hear you're having problems. Some things to try:

1. Install [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/)
2. In the Windows Start menu locate the Ruby program group and run "Start Command Prompt with Ruby"
3. At the prompt type `gem install compass`

You should see something like this:

```
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30) [i386-mingw32]

C:\>gem install compass
Fetching: sass-3.1.15.gem (100%)
Fetching: chunky_png-1.2.5.gem (100%)
Fetching: fssm-0.2.8.1.gem (100%)
Fetching: compass-0.11.7.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.1.15
Successfully installed chunky_png-1.2.5
Successfully installed fssm-0.2.8.1
Successfully installed compass-0.11.7
4 gems installed
```

Does this work? If so then you're good to go. You'll also need to install Slim: `gem install slim`. Try following the [Compass install documentation](http://compass-style.org/install/) from here. The commands for Windows are identical to those for Mac/Linux. If you need some help learning about the Windows command line, there are [plenty of tutorials around](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows%20command%20line%20tutorial&kl=uk-en).

Take a look at [Compass.app](http://compass.handlino.com/) and [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/) if you really don't get on with the command line. I really do recommend getting to grips with the command line, though. It's a very handy skill to possess.

I'd recommend using a simple text editor rather than an IDE. I prefer Sublime Text 2, but Notepad++ or Scite might suit you better. RubyMine is a good IDE, but it's not exactly simple.

Forget Git for now - you don't need it for what you're trying to do (compile Sass and Slim files).

One final parting thought: what you're after doing it roughly equal in difficulty on a Mac, so purchasing one wouldn't, at this stage, make life much easier for you. In the long-run, though, if you get into, say, Rails development seriously, then a Mac would make life easier. If you're simply compiling Sass and Slim, though, no need to switch. The authors have done a great job cross-platform job.

Comment: thanks! it totally worked! i'm halfway through learning sinatra already. ruby makes php look like a joke. :D